# How can I create a hosted zone on AWS Route53 for a IDN domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

As I understand AWS route53 supports idn domains defining the domain name using octal, but I haven’t been able to make the “ñ” character I need.

I’ve tried with \361 on the domain name field on the web console without any success.

Ref.: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DomainNameFormat.html

Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Have you converted your domain name to punycode ?

Comment: converted the comment to an answer for others benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to convert the domain name to [punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) as mentioned in the [official documentation](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DomainNameFormat.html)

> When you register a new domain name or create hosted zones and
>   records, you can specify characters in other alphabets (for example,
>   Cyrillic or Arabic) and characters in Chinese, Japanese, or Korean.
>   Amazon Route 53 stores these internationalized domain names (IDNs) in
>   Punycode, which represents Unicode characters as ASCII strings.
>
> The following example shows the Punycode representation of the
>   internationalized domain name 中国.asia:
>
> xn--fiqs8s.asia
>
> When you enter an IDN in the address bar of a modern browser, the
>   browser converts it to Punycode before submitting a DNS query or
>   making an HTTP request.
>
> How you enter an IDN depends on what you're creating (domain names,
>   hosted zones, or records), and how you're creating it (API, SDK, or
>   Route 53 console):
>
> If you're using the Route 53 API or one of the AWS SDKs, you can
>   programmatically convert a Unicode value to Punycode. For example, if
>   you're using Java, you can convert a Unicode value to Punycode by
>   using the toASCII method of the java.net.IDN library.
>
> If you're using the Route 53 console to register a domain name, you
>   can paste the name, including Unicode characters, into the name field,
>   and the console converts the value to Punycode before saving it.
>
> If you're using the Route 53 console to create hosted zones or
>   records, you need to convert the domain name to Punycode before you
>   enter the name in the applicable Name field. For information about
>   online converters, perform an internet search on "punycode converter".